# f90 set parameter of two dimensions (:,:) in a module

Tags: parameters, declaration, fortran90

Good evening,

I am working on f90 and I am trying to introduce  a 2D parameter of dimensions 9x2 values just like:

```
integer, parameter:: v(0:8,0) = (/0,1,0,-1,0,1,-1,-1,1/)
integer, parameter:: v(0:8,1) = (/0,0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1/)
```

but actually, it doesn't work, the error that apears after compiling is:

```
--> gfortran -c main.f90
```

> main.f90:40.31:
>
> integer, parameter:: v(0:8,0) = (/0,1,0,-1,0,1,-1,-1,1/)
>
> Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)
>
> main.f90:41.31:
>
> integer, parameter:: v(0:8,1) = (/0,0,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1/)
>
> Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)

but I dont understand the problem.

I would really appreciat someone's help to fix this trivial error.

Thank you in advance.

Puigar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define an array twice, and that's not allowed. What you want to do is

```
integer, parameter :: v(9,2) = reshape( (/0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 1,-1,-1, 1,&
                                          0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 1, 1,-1,-1/),(/9,2/))
```

Note that Fortran is 1-indexed by default; if you wanted, you'd be able to do this with 0-index, but it's a minor change to the above.

Comment: integer, parameter :: v(0:8,0:1) = reshape( (/0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 1,-1,-1, 1,&
                                          0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 1, 1,-1,-1/),(/9,2/))
I put it like this then?

Comment: Like I said, a minor change. The bigger issue is that you were trying to define an array twice (`integer, parameter :: v(0:8,0)` & `integer, parameter :: v(0:8,1)`) when you only wanted one array.

Comment: No problem @AlbertPa. If this answer has helped you, you can click the check-mark under to the left to show that this was the correct solution.